# HTC Desire 500 - how to root

Tags: rooting, htc-desire-500

I am completely new to this.

But I need to root my HTC Desire 500 to get rid of some virus that my phone caught unfortunately.

I have been googling etc. but I am not sure whether the information and tools there are up 2 date.

Is there ONE link/resource with an actual and updated to-do step by step process to root my phone? Or can someone possibly describe the steps I need to make without breaking my phone or something?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! While waiting for an answer specific to your device, be welcome to check with our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) (where I've just linked your question to) and our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). The former also lists some more-or-less generic methods, from which one might apply in your case. Also, please [edit] your question and include which Android version your device is currently running.

Comment: Normally a wipe will get rid of any unvanted program (but will wipe all you settings and data).